# Problem with terminal while doctrine:create:database

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine

I've got a problem with doctrine.
I've configured well my .env file, like that:

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8888/tuto"
```

and then in the console I put:

```
symfony console doctrine:database:create
```

but then it does not display anything, the console loads and that's it

Can anyone helps me ? thanks in advance guys :)

Comment: I take it you have the CLI installed, but try `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` in your project directory.

Comment: same problem ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:8888/tuto?serverVersion=8.0&charset=utf8mb4"
```

This is a right syntax i think, put your serverVersion and charset

Comment: I changed it and it's still loading :(

Comment: try php bin/console doctrine:schema:create

Comment: I did it, still the same

Comment: any database changes ?

Comment: I changed the port and it's works now... sorry guys :// and thanks for your time

Comment: I'm always getting error when i put wrong port. This is weird.

Comment: @Jsmarchewka, by default MySQL is on port 3306.

Comment: I’m always using docker so my ports are different.

Comment: @Jsmarchewka, then as per your docker/docker-compose setup..